Restarting the appropriate chunk due to abnormal shutdown of the spring batch
There might be some awkward parts because of the translator
I'm in the process of deploying and I'm going to start again when I'm out of trouble
job execution-exit_code = unknown
step execution-exit_code = started
At this time, there is a problem that a new job is about to be executed without starting from where it ended, so could you tell me how I can test it out?
1. incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) When using this method, the job parameters continue to be newly created, so it seems that the job that has ended cannot be executed.
2. When I removed the incrementer(), It says that duplicate job parameters are not available. So, I don't think this can be executed from the closed job either.
What I want to check is, 'Can I start with the chunk of that job if I run it again when the job isn't complete for many reasons?'
Please let me know if there is anything I missed..
I tried to remove the center


When you use an incrementer, you will always have a new job instance.

If you want to restart the same job instance, you need to re-run the job with the same parameters. If the first run was shutdown abruptly, you need to change the status of the job execution to FAILED and set its END_TIME to a non null value (same thing for the failed step) to be able to restart it from the last chunk.


There is a note about this case in the reference documentation here: Aborting a Job.
